# ASP.NET 5 Console Application (package) - How to create DBContext from connection string?

Tags: c#, console-application, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm trying to create DBContext from connection string on .net core. This used to work with .net 4.5:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   internal MYContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString){}
}
```

Now I'm getting error that the base class (DBContext) doesn't have constructor that accepts string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DbContext](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/0e4716d555f290b54a5358e71fe616b958d65cb5/src/EntityFramework.Core/DbContext.cs) doesn't have this constructor anymore. You can specify the connection string in `OnConfiguring` method overload:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {         
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");

    }
}
```

https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/full-dotnet/new-db.html

`UseSqlServer` is an [extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/0e4716d555f290b54a5358e71fe616b958d65cb5/src/EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.cs#L22) for `DbContextOptionsBuilder`

Comment: The method signiture I see is:
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
And DbContextOptionsBuilder/DbContextOptions don't have .UseSQLServer() methods. I'm using EF 7 RC. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So how to pass the connection string?

Comment: Uning DBContextOptionsBuilder, not the DBContextOptions.

Comment: Example will be appreciated. As I said I can't see DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer().

Comment: Have you installed  EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer NuGet package?

Comment: I've just added it. Now I can see the extension method. Thanks.